# Formatting an integer x.xxxxx as xx.xxx

Tags: powershell, formatting

I have a number, `$int`,

```
$int = 9.5587452369
```

I want this number to be in the format xx.xxx
I tried:

```
$int = "{0:N3}" -f ($int)
$int = "{0:D2}" -f ($int)
```

or

```
$int = "{0:D2}" -f ("{0:N3}" -f ($int))
```

But it doesn't work. Any Ideas?

Comment: That does not look like an *integer*.

Comment: Why do you use the name `$int`? It is misleading. The number 9.5587452369 is not an [integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `toString()` method with specified format.

```
PS > $int = 9.5587452369
PS > $int.ToString("00.000")
09,559
```

Or

```
PS > "{0:00.000}" -f $int
09,559
```

Read more at [MSDN - Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: Perfect, the second one works well (I have to use it as an Integer)
Didn't know "Personnal formatting" was possible
Thanks !